# Solutions of a logarithmic equation.

Tags: logarithms

> Equation from Question:
>
> [image]
>
> $$x^{(\log_3(x))^2 + \log_3(x^4)-3}=3^{2\log_3(x)}$$
>
> The question states to find the number of solutions and the sum of integral solutions. The correct answer is 3 solutions of integral sum 4

#### Solution attempt

[image]

According to my solution, I only get two solutions out of which only one is integral (3).
Please help me in finding the mistake.

PS: Sorry for not typing the equation but I don't know how to do so on phone! Also, Stack wouldn't let me post images because of repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $t=\log_3 x$. Then,on taking $\log_3$ on both sides, we get -
$$(t^2+4t-3)t=2t$$
Simplifying, we get $t=0,1,-5$, or $x=1,3,3^{\frac{1}{5}}$. Hence, sum of integral solutions $=4$

Comment: Thanks! For the case when t=0!